# Implementation of Google DataTable class

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I downloaded http://www.google.com/uds/modules/gviz/gviz-api.js, included it in my html file and added the following to my JavaScript code.

```
var numRows = 50.0;
var numCols = 50;

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  data.addRows(numRows);

  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) 
  {
            for (var j = 0; j < numCols; j++)
            {
              data.setValue(i, j, 1.0);
            }
  }

  var debugNumRows=data.getNumberOfRows();
```

I find that debugNumRows is undefined and the reason is that getNumberOfRows() consists of the following in gviz-api.js.

```
google.visualization.DataTable.prototype.getNumberOfRows = function() {};
```

If this is an API, does that mean that it needs an implementation?  Am I supposed to implement it myself?  I was not able to find a discussion about it [here](http://data-gov.tw.rpi.edu/wiki/How_to_use_Google_Visualization_API).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to download the API like that (in fact, it is forbidden in the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/chart/terms)).  Load it properly via the Google loader, and you shouldn't have any problems:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo() {/* chart code */}
    google.setOnLoadCallback(foo);
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: [/* list of whatever packages you need */]});
</script>
```

Comment: I thought this link https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference was saying to download the file but I have deleted what I downloaded and what you suggest works.  Thanks very much!